# SVG animation acts differently in webkit browsers than in gecko

Tags: animation, svg, cross-browser, webkit, svg-animate

**EDIT**
THIS was my final result. Maybe it will help someone out there ->

```html
<svg width="300" height="225">
    <circle class="st5" r="21" style="opacity: 0;">
        <animateMotion id="circle1" dur="10s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
        <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="10s" keyTimes="0;0.15;0.95;1" values="0;1;1;0" begin="circle1.begin" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

I have a problem with an SVG animation.

I want 2 circles to follow the paths to the right.
Then I want 1 circle to follow path 1, back to the left.
Then I wan 2 circles to follow the paths to the right again.
Then I want 1 circle to follow path 2, back to the left.
Then the animation starts from the beginning.

In Firefox this works great.
Only in Chrome and Safari the animation "back" does not happen. The circles follow the path to the right and then do not move back to the left.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?
Do I have a stupid mistake in there that I don't see that triggers this?

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1478.2 1091.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1478.2 1091.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    
    #way1{fill:none;stroke:#003584;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    #way2{fill:none;stroke:#003584;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    
</style>

<path id="way1" class="" d="M321.6,581.6c0,0,123.8-42.1,255.6,57.9c87.5,71.1,179.7,64.2,301.7,46
        c110.3-17.6,220.1-81,241.4-171.4c14.6-73.1,56.8-96.5,116.7-96.1"></path>
<path id="way2" class="" d="M321.2,582c164.4,7.3,159.4,161.4,400.2,207.2c420.4,75.6,323.1,183.3,509,192.6"></path>

<circle id="circle1" style="opacity: 0;" class="st8" r="21">
    <animateMotion id="circle1anim" dur="3s" begin="0;circle6anim.end" path="M321.6,581.6c0,0,123.8-42.1,255.6,57.9c87.5,71.1,179.7,64.2,301.7,46
        c110.3-17.6,220.1-81,241.4-171.4c14.6-73.1,56.8-96.5,116.7-96.1"></animateMotion>
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.9;1" values="0;1;1;0" begin="0;circle6anim.end"></animate>
</circle>
<circle id="circle2" style="opacity: 0;" class="st8" r="21">
    <animateMotion id="circle2anim" dur="3s" begin="0;circle6anim.end" path="M321.2,582c164.4,7.3,159.4,161.4,400.2,207.2c420.4,75.6,323.1,183.3,509,192.6"></animateMotion>
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.9;1" values="0;1;1;0" begin="0;circle6anim.end"></animate>
</circle>

<circle id="circle3" style="opacity: 0;" class="st8" r="21">
    <animateMotion id="circle3anim" dur="3s" begin="circle1anim.end" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" path="M321.6,581.6c0,0,123.8-42.1,255.6,57.9c87.5,71.1,179.7,64.2,301.7,46
        c110.3-17.6,220.1-81,241.4-171.4c14.6-73.1,56.8-96.5,116.7-96.1"></animateMotion>
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.9;1" values="0;1;1;0" begin="circle1anim.end"></animate>
</circle>

<circle id="circle4" style="opacity: 0;" class="st8" r="21">
    <animateMotion id="circle4anim" dur="3s" begin="circle3anim.end" path="M321.6,581.6c0,0,123.8-42.1,255.6,57.9c87.5,71.1,179.7,64.2,301.7,46
        c110.3-17.6,220.1-81,241.4-171.4c14.6-73.1,56.8-96.5,116.7-96.1"></animateMotion>
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.9;1" values="0;1;1;0" begin="circle3anim.end"></animate>
</circle>

<circle id="circle5" style="opacity: 0;" class="st8" r="21">
    <animateMotion id="circle5anim" dur="3s" begin="circle3anim.end" path="M321.2,582c164.4,7.3,159.4,161.4,400.2,207.2c420.4,75.6,323.1,183.3,509,192.6"></animateMotion>
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.9;1" values="0;1;1;0" begin="0;circle3anim.end"></animate>
</circle>

<circle id="circle6" style="opacity: 0;" class="st8" r="21">
    <animateMotion id="circle6anim" dur="3s" begin="circle4anim.end" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" path="M321.2,582c164.4,7.3,159.4,161.4,400.2,207.2c420.4,75.6,323.1,183.3,509,192.6"></animateMotion>
    <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.9;1" values="0;1;1;0" begin="0;circle4anim.end"></animate>
</circle>


</svg>
```

Comment: You could always try raising bugs on Chrome and Webkit's bugtrackers.

Comment: thanks for the hint, i'll do that right away